# How to load a view from a view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, symfony, view, twig

I used to work with CodeIgniter. Now I am starting to learn Symfony2. I was just wondering, in CodeIgniter I could load a view from another view. Like, I could load menu.php from index.php. This is how I used to do it -

```
//in index.php
<?php $this->load->view('menu.php'); ?>
```

Is it possible to do the same thing in Symfony2 and Twig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways you can do it depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

If you want to render the response of a controller you can do this in your twig template.

```
{{ render(controller('AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentArticles', {
        'max': 3
})) }}
```

In the above example, the parameter passed `max` would be passed as an argument to your controller.  Then the controller would be responsible for returning a response that will be inserted into the view where it was called from.

You can also use `include` to render just the twig template as an embedded view:

```
{% for article in articles %}
    {{ include(
        'AcmeArticleBundle:Article:articleDetails.html.twig',
        { 'article': article }
    ) }}
{% endfor %}
```

In the above example `article` would be passed into the context of the twig template `articleDetails.html.twig` but not to any controller.  So this method is ideal for repetitious front-end code that is used in many places such as templates for tables, lists, sidebars, etc.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-other-templates
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/include.html